# Run 1 pod on master node, and the remaining pods on worker node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster with one master node and one worker node.

I would like to deploy a group of pods so that there is always only one pod on the master node, and any additional pods are scheduled on the worker node.

I have tried this with node affinity and pod anti affinity,

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - master-node
  affinity:  
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
       - labelSelector:
           matchExpressions:
           - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
             operator: In
             values:
             - master-node
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

however this seems to share the pods evenly between the nodes, so in a deployment of 4 pods I could end up with 2 pods on each node which I do not want.

How can I maintain only 1 pod on the master, and the rest on the worker(s)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to run pods on master nodes because this is an antipattern. But you can do that . You need to remove a taint on the master nodes. This will remove the node-role.kubernetes.io/master taint from any nodes that have it, including the control-plane node, meaning that the scheduler will then be able to schedule pods everywhere

Comment: I have added a toleration to the pod spec to allow scheduling on the master node, so this is not an issue. I would just like to schedule only one on the master node as a backup due to the way the servers are set up, and further pods on the worker nodes, this all being from the same deployment. Thanks